# return null with query string whtn i use ajax-jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

this is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").hover(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"Dbread.aspx",

                data: "name=salam",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);


                } //end of success




            });


        }, function () {



        });


    });

</script>
```

in Dbread.aspx
i wrote:

```
      string str= Request.QueryString["name"];
    Response.Write(str);
```

but the problem is that query string result is null all times!!!
what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using method "POST" and not providing actual query string. Query string is created only for "GET" method and should be the part of the URL, so the fix would be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"Dbread.aspx?name=salam",
    ...
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"Dbread.aspx",
    data: "name=salam",
    ...
```

Comment: that's right. thanks.please excuse me for this stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

This is the best practice.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"Dbread.aspx",
    data: {name:"salam",qs:"bla"},  //also i appended the qs parameter
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);

    } //end of success
});
```

Answer (score 0):

extra space can cause this problem

```
PrintPreview.NavigateUrl = "~/ReportViewer.aspx?ReviewID=" + Session["ArticleID"].ToString() + " & User=" + (Session["ID"]).ToString();
```

above is not working it returns null in ID

but in the below example it works fine just change of space character

```
PrintPreview.NavigateUrl = "~/ReportViewer.aspx?ReviewID= " + Session["ArticleID"].ToString() + "&User=" + (Session["ID"]).ToString();
```

http://afzal-gujrat.blogspot.com/